# Screen resolution and multiple monitors Kubuntu 11.10 Asus U46E BAL7

Tags: multiple-monitors, kubuntu, screen

I have just installed Kubuntu on ASUS U46E BAL7. The installation went fine and I am able to use the desktop. But it seems to recognize only one monitor at a time, either the laptop or the secondary one and not both. Besides this the resolution being shown is far less than the capability of either monitors.

I was able to generate a xorg.conf file, but that seems to be mostly empty. I am skeptical about editing it and screwing up what's working now. Is there a way to dump existing configuration that kubuntu is using into a file, so I can work by modifying those settings as opposed to writing everything by hand ?

Please find my xorg.conf file attached below.

Thanks million in advance.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "extmod"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "DRI"                   # []
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # 
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # []
        #Option     "Tiling"                # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # []
        #Option     "Shadow"                # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # []
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # []
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # []
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"        # []
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # []
        #Option     "Rotate"                # 
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # 
        #Option     "debug"                 # []
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # []
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # []
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # []
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewpo
rt   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Thanks
Venkat

EDIT: Moved a bunch of data from an answer section non-answer into the question:

Thanks for the reply. I have spent significant amount of time trying to install ubuntu on this new piece of hardware. None of the 11.10 64bit versions boot up for some reason. So I went ahead and installed Server first and installed KDE after the server installation was complete. Besides the

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

I have not done much. I wonder if I missed any installations that are needed and this might be causing the problem. Your thoughts ....

EDIT

Apologies. Trouble with this output is I personally cannot understand it as it doesn't have any version info. So, I assumed output of lshw would have more info.

Output of lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

EDIT

xrandr output:

`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      77.0*`

EDIT

Yes, I have the external monitor hooked up. If I have it hooked up during start it defaults to the external one and shows only that. It not, it defaults to laptop screen and shows only that.

EDIT March 04 2012 2:32 PM

This the error startx gives me.

```
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-16-server #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 18:03:45 UTC 2012 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-server root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro noapic nomodeset
Build Date: 19 October 2011 05:21:26AM
xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.22.2 
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Mar 4 14:16:45 2012
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) No devices detected.

Fatal Server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
    at http://wiki.x.org 
 for help

Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.org" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Comment: So far what I have noticed is this. 
 
Only the vesa driver seems to load the monitors. As you mentioned I have three devices configured. I am not sure why that is. 

-> I commented out the last one. 
-> Removed the third monitor
-> Configured the other two monitors to use one Intel (Card0) ( x-server fails to start )
-> Configured the monitors to VESA and the x-server starts up but only runs one monitor. 

Here is the laptop configuration. 
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Asus+-+Laptop+-+Aluminum+Platinum/4566459.p?id=1218492325284&skuId=4566459

Comment: Yeah...when they fix the intel driver bug the xorg.conf below should work.  Until then it's a driver bug.  Dual monitors with a vesa driver is probably a no-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to `Kubuntu 12.04 LTS` with `noapic` enabled and `nolapic` and `nomodeset` removed solved this issue, if anybody is looking for it. If you have upgraded to 12.04 and not removed `nolapic` and `nomodeset`, it will not solve the issue. I am now able to view dual monitors at their highest resolution. Please let me know if anybody is unable to see this behaviour, I will report it on the bug or better yet report it yourself.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/912397

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
First back up the one you have...you can always boot to a terminal and restore it.

Then, you could try this one:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "extmod"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Intel"
        Driver         "intel"
        Option          "monitor-VGA" "A"
        Option          "monitor-LVDS" "B"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "A"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "B"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier    "Screen0"
        Device        "Intel"
        Monitor       "A"
        DefaultDepth  24
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth          24
                Modes         "1280x1024"  "1024x768"   "640x480"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen1"
        Device        "Intel"
        Monitor       "B"
        DefaultDepth  24
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth          24
                Modes         "1280x1024"  "1024x768"   "640x480"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

/EDIT

It seems highly irregular to me that you're using a vesa driver with 3 monitors.  Maybe you should try using a specific driver for your hardware.  I use the proprietary ATI driver and this is my config for reference:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1" LeftOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-2" LeftOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-2"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-2"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      2
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
                Modes "1440x900_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
                Modes "1440x900_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-2"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-2"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-2"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
                Modes "1440x900_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

EDIT: I looked over your config again and I see three different devices, but maybe you should include something about your hardware setup for more helpful answers...

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/912397